# Handling java exception handle. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

> Blockquote Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
>       at twoDArray.sumTwoDim(twoDArray.java:11)
>       at twoDArray.main(twoDArray.java:61)

New to java programming. Trying to run this code and kept getting this error. This code is basically creating 2d arrays with random numbers and trying to rotate it to the right, left, and flip. Im not at this part yet im just trying to make sure the code actually prints the correct arrays but im not sure what to do.

```
 class twoDArray
{

 public static int sumTwoDim (int [][] intMatrix)

{
int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i< intMatrix.length; i++)
  {
      for (int j = 0; j<intMatrix[0].length;i++)
      {
         sum +=  intMatrix[i][j];
      }
   }
         return sum;
}
   public static void printMatrix( int [][] intMatrix)
   {
        for (int i = 0; i< intMatrix.length; i++)
         {
           for (int j = 0; j<intMatrix[0].length;i++)
               {
                       if (intMatrix[i][j]<10)
                          System.out.print(" ");
                             System.out.print(intMatrix[i][j]+ " ");
                }
                             System.out.println();
              }
        } 
   public static int[][] rotateRight(int[][] intMatrix)
    {
      int [][] matrix = new int[3][4];

    int [][] rotateMatrix = new int[intMatrix[0].length] [intMatrix.length];
      for(int i = 0; i <intMatrix.length; i++)
   {
       for(int j = 0; j <intMatrix.length; j++)
   {
      rotateMatrix[i][j] = intMatrix[j][i];
     }
  }
       return rotateMatrix;
    }


  public static void main(String[] args)
{
  System.out.println("Hello world!");

  int[][] matrix = new int[3][4];
  int val = 5;

  for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
     for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        matrix[i][j] = val++;

  int sum = sumTwoDim(matrix);
  System.out.println("The sum of all values in matrix 1 is " + sum);

  int[][] matrix2 = new int[5][3];
  val = 2;

  for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
     for(int j = 0; j<3; j++)
        matrix2[i][j] = val++;

        sum = sumTwoDim(matrix2);


    System.out.println("The sum of all values in matrix 2 is " + sum); 
    printMatrix(matrix2);
    printMatrix(rotateRight(matrix2));     
    } 
}
```

Comment: change `for (int j = 0; j<intMatrix[0].length;i++)` to `for (int j = 0; j<intMatrix[i].length;i++)`

Comment: @ScaryWombat still getting the same error